# R Error creating notebook: clipboard mode

Tags: r, r-markdown, clipboard, rnotebook

I'm getting an error I've never seen before when trying to preview my R notebook. I get the following error from RStudio. [image]

It only happens on the one notebook and there are no errors from R itself in the console running all the chunks, and they seem to run fine individually. I've copied each bit to a new notebook and tried to preview this new notebook with the same outcome.

```
output:
 html_notebook:
  toc: yes
  toc_depth: '3'
  toc_float: yes
  number_sections: no
editor_options:
 chunk_output_type: inline
```

Comment: might just need to restart R, update packages, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very satisfying solution but I am able to get it working if I delete a folder called "0.1 clipboard" within the `User/AppData/RStudio-Desktop/notebooks/[notebook name]/1/s/lib` directory.